# How to manage nested formGroup in Angular?

Tags: angular8, nested-forms, formgroups

I have created a dynamic form using formGroup and formArray, and need to get  `repItems` inside the `repForm` in HTML, but got the following error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
>       at Object.eval [as updateDirectives]

How to resolve it without using formBuilder?

My code:

```js
ngOnInit() { 
            this.quizForm = new FormGroup({
             items: new FormArray([new FormGroup({
              question: new FormControl('',Validators.required),
              repOne: new FormControl(''),
              repForm: new FormGroup({
                repItems:new FormArray([new FormGroup({
                  rep: new FormControl('',Validators.required)
                })])
              })
            })])
            })
          }
```

```html
    <form [formGroup]="quizForm" #formDir="ngForm">
                <div formArrayName="items" *ngFor="let item of quizForm.get('items').controls; let i = index;">
                    <div [formGroupName]="i">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="question">Question</label>
                            <input id="question" class="form-control" formControlName="question">
                            </div>
                        <div formGroupName="repForm">
                                <div formArrayName="repItems"
                                    *ngFor="let repItem of repForm.get('repItems').controls; let r = repIndex;">
                                    <div [formGroupName]="r">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="rep">Response</label>
                                            <input id="rep" class="form-control"
                                                formControlName="rep">
                                        </div>
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"
                                            (click)='removeRepItem(r)'>RemoveForm</button>
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" (click)='addRepItem()'>addForm</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" (click)='removeItem(i)'>RemoveForm</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </form>
```

Comment: Can you console.log `repForm.get('repItems')` and see what control type it is.

Comment: console.log for  repForm.get('repItems') get:ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined